# input type number (number and required) validation

Tags: angularjs

How to validate `input type="number'`??

i want two validations: 1. required 2. it should only number

i've tried it so far:

```
<form name="myFrm">
    <input type="number" name="myName" ng-model="id" required />

    <p ng-show="myFrm.myName.$error.number">It should only contain numbers.</p>
    <p ng-show="myFrm.myName.$error.required">It is required.</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely related to a known bug which they claimed to have fixed but don't seem to have.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6Zg2/).

The associated issue/bug is [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6818).

The error result is:

```
{ required: true, number: false }
```

Whereas it should be:

```
{ required: false, number: true }
```

Apparently beta 13 should've fixed it with the introduction of the validator pipeline and such, but it doesn't seem to have.

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
<p ng-show="myFrm.myName.$error.required">It is required.</p>
```

with

```
<p ng-show="myFrm.myName.$error.required && !myFrm.myName.$error.number">It is required.</p>
```

hope this help!